# How to attach media file to woocommerce order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to attach media file after payment completion of order, for that I am using the filter "woocommerce_order_status_completed" with below snippet. But it is not attaching files to downloads tab of my account page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'attach_files' );
function attach_files($order_id){
 $order =  wc_get_order($order_id);
 $md5_num = md5( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/abc.png');
 $files[$md5_num] = array(
    'download_url' => 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/abc.png',
    'download_name' => 'Download',
    'downloads_remaining' => '1',
    'access_expires' => NULL,
    'download_id' => '7f7e4923ff94b7928c0b8b5e93fb4f89',
    'product_id' => 17,  
    'order_id' => $order_id,
    'order_key' => 'wc_order_5a382bef811e6',
    'file' => array (
        'name' => 'Download',
        'file' => 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/abc.png',
        ),
    );

 update_post_meta($order_id,'_files',$files);
 }
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The My account > Downloads section, just allow access **exclusively** the **authorized** downloads from **purchased downloadable products only**, but not any other kind of attached files to an order. What you can do is to attach a file for completed status email notification: [see those related answer threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=woocommerce_email_attachments)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Is order attachment not work? Do I have to add files to email only?

Comment: In woocommerce by default, YES… Now you can always develop (or extend) a feature as you like, if you have the skills and the time to spend on it…